# Автоматический скроллинг ul

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5

Мне необходимо сделать так, чтобы при входе на страницу начинался скролл 
Я немного не понимаю как это можно реализовать, хоть и представляю себе картину кода

Пример: https://youtu.be/K9_dJqUZ-2g?t=25

Код -

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>...</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
        <script rel="stylesheet" href="js"></script>
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Amatic+SC&family=Shadows+Into+Light+Two&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body class="redglet">
        <div class="r">
            <ul>Бла-Бла</ul>
            <ul>Бла-Бла</ul>
            <ul>Бла-Бла</ul>
            <ul>Бла-Бла</ul>
            <ul>Бла-Бла</ul>
            <ul>Бла-Бла</ul>
            <ul>Бла-Бла</ul>
            <ul>Бла-Бла</ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: А что вы пробовали? А что означает строка `<script rel="stylesheet" href="js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте воспользоватся каким нибудь фраемворком, если не помогает есть другой варинат: https://www.cyberforum.ru/javascript/thread1348521.html

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. — [из очереди проверок](/review/late-answers/695620)